# how to split string url in java

Tags: java

I wonder how I can split string url to host and port.
Suppose I have

```
 String http://localhost:1213
```

and I want to have host=  "localhost" and port (as integer or long) = 1213.

I did this:

```
     String[] parts = URL.split(":");
     String HOST = parts[0]; 
     String PORT = parts[1];
```

but it gave me: HOST = htp// and PORT = localhost obviously since it splitted till ":"
Any help of how to get them in a correct way and have port as long instead of string?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just use `Integer.parseInt()` for the port variable:

```
 String[] parts = VAC_URL.split(":");
 String HOST = parts[1].replaceAll("//","");
 int PORT = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
```

or to have it as long use this instead:

```
long PORT = Long.valueOf(parts[2]).longValue();
```

Comment: What about the `//` then?

Comment: Right, replied too fast. This should be better.

Comment: This is broken for IPv6 literals. If the URL is `http://[::1]:80/foo.html` (which is the IPv6 equivalent of `http://128.0.0.1:80/foo.html`) then this naive parsing won't work. Instead, use the URL class mentioned in another answer which properly handles this kind of complexity so you don't need to worry about it.

Answer (score 11):

You could use the [URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) class, which will also give you validation to ensure your url is correct.

It has a `getHost` and a `getPort` method that give you exactly what you need.

```
URL u = new URL(VAC_URL);
String host = u.getHost();
int port = u.getPort();
```

The constructor will throw an exception if the URL is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get return your host with protocol and port, example: "http://127.0.0.1"  and "9090"   so here is the function I have Created check it up...

```
public static String[] divideHostPort(String hostWithPort) {

    String hostProtocol;
    String[] urlParts = new String[2];


    if (hostWithPort.startsWith("http://")) {
        hostProtocol = "http://";
        hostWithPort = hostWithPort.replace(hostProtocol, "");

        if (hostWithPort.split(":").length == 2) {

            urlParts[0] = hostProtocol + hostWithPort.split(":")[0];
            urlParts[1] = hostWithPort.split(":")[1];

        } else {
            urlParts[0] = hostProtocol +hostWithPort;
            urlParts[1] = "80";
        }


        return urlParts;

    } else if (hostWithPort.startsWith("https://")) {
        hostProtocol = "https://";
        hostWithPort = hostWithPort.replace(hostProtocol, "");

        if (hostWithPort.split(":").length == 2) {

            urlParts[0] = hostProtocol + hostWithPort.split(":")[0];
            urlParts[1] = hostWithPort.split(":")[1];

        } else {
            urlParts[0] = hostProtocol + hostWithPort;
            urlParts[1] = "80";
        }


        return urlParts;
    } else {

        hostProtocol = "http://";

        if (hostWithPort.split(":").length == 2) {

            urlParts[0] = hostProtocol + hostWithPort.split(":")[0];
            urlParts[1] = hostWithPort.split(":")[1];

        } else {
            urlParts[0] = hostProtocol + hostWithPort;
            urlParts[1] = "80";
        }


        return urlParts;

    }


}
```

Call it Like `String arr[]=divideHostPort("http://127.0.0.1:9090")`

to retrieve both details use array like `String host=arr[0]` and `String port=arr[1]`

Answer (score -1):

```
 String s= http://localhost:1213
 String[] parts = s.split(":");
 String HOST = parts[1].replaceAll("//",""); // part[0] is http, part[1] is //localhost, part[2] is 1213
 String PORT = parts[2];
```

Comment: It gave me this: HOST=" "
PORT=localhost:12

Comment: @user3409650 - paste your String here